# Tabulator image enlarge on click

Tags: reactjs, tabulator

I am new to reactjs and I am new to tabulator. I am using a tabulator to show a row which also has an image in one of the columns, as shown below.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XhhS1.png)

I want to enlarge the image to its original size. How can I achieve this.

This is the code below:

```
const ForwardInventoryColumns=[
      {formatter:"responsiveCollapse", width:100, minWidth:100, align:"center", resizable:false, 
      headerSort:false},
      {
        title: "",
        field: "",
        align: "center",
        
        
        headerSort:false,
        
        formatter: reactFormatter(<UpdateDataButton />),        
      },
      
      { title: "Type", field: "type", minWidth : 100, headerSort: false,headerFilter: "input", 
       headerFilterPlaceholder:"search...",visible:true},
      { title: "ID", field: "id", minWidth : 100, headerSort: false,headerFilter: "input", 
       headerFilterPlaceholder:"search...",visible:true},
      { title: "Description", field: "desc", minWidth : 100, headerSort: false,headerFilter: "input", 
       headerFilterPlaceholder:"search...",
      editor: "number", editorParams: {allowEmpty: false},cellEdited:this.updateTableData,  
        validator: 
       {type:"max", parameters:99999999 },visible:true},
      { title: "ImageURL", field: "imgurl", minWidth : 100, headerSort: false,headerFilter: "input", 
       headerFilterPlaceholder:"search...",
       editorParams: {allowEmpty: false},cellEdited:this.updateTableData , validator:{type:"max", 
       parameters:99999999 },visible:true,formatter:"image", formatterParams:{height:"50px",
       width:"50px",
       urlPrefix:"http://website.com/images/",
       urlSuffix:".png",
          }},
      { title: "Active", field: "active", minWidth : 100, headerSort: false,headerFilter: "input", 
      headerFilterPlaceholder:"search...",
      editor: "number", editorParams: {allowEmpty: false},cellEdited:this.updateTableData , 
      validator: 
      {type:"max", parameters:99999999 },visible:true}
```

Answer (score 0):

the quick and dirty ? set your width parameter in the formatterParams to something larger. (or get rid of height + width entirely and just put it in the minWidth column attribute)

The longer and more complicated, you're probably going to have to walk the rows, getting the actual <img> in the imgurl field, get its width and keep track of the widest image. Then use

```
updateColumnDefinition("imgurl", {minWidth:savedMaxWidth});
```

The problem I see with this is **WHEN** do you walk the rows to find the largest image ? You prolly dont know when the browser has pulled all the images to know that its time to go search and find the biggest image ?

Comment: oh wait, you wanted to "pop it out" at full size when you click on the image ? well you can use the cellClick column callback to populate a <div style="z-index:10"> with the full sized image so it floats above the Tabulator. You'll need to provide a way to close it too, so an **X** in the corner is standard UI type of build

Answer (score 0):

well not working code, but the general idea...

```
<div id='dialog' style='display:none;z-index:2;width:100%;height:100%:position:relative'>
    <span style='position:absolute:top:0:right:0' onclick="document.getElementById('dialog').style.display='none'"><b>X</b></span>
    <img id='blowup' src=''>
</div>
<div id="tabulator"></div>

...

cellclick:function(e,cell) {
   document.getElementById('blowup').src = cell.getValue();
   document.getElementById('dialog').style.display = 'block';
},
```

Comment: My image src is dynamic how do i add that in the src template?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/0nemujtq/1/

fill in your blanks ....